# Validation of a JSP page with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I would like to validate the AGE and the NAME field, meaning when the user click on the "Modify" button and these fields are empty, then it should color the fields to pink/red and doesn't let to submit the form.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ page import="flightPartner.Person" %>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<%
String idParam=request.getParameter("id");
if(idParam!=null){
   Person candidate=Person.getPersonById(idParam);
   if(candidate!=null) request.setAttribute("candidate",candidate);
}
%>


<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
        $('form[name="modifyForm"]').validate({
            errorClass: 'jqInvalid',
            rules: {
                name: "required",
                age: "required",
            },
            messages: {
                name: "",
                age: "",
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                element.css('background', '#ffdddd');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Modify ${candidate.name}</h1>
    <form action="registerServlet?todo=modify&candidateA=${candidate.id}" method="POST" name="modifyForm">
        <h2>Name</h2>
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="30" id="name" required="true" />
        <h2>Age</h2>
        <input type="text" name="Age" value="" size="3" id="age" required="true" />
        <h2>Gender</h2>
        <select name="Gender">
            <option value="F">Female</option>
            <option value="M">Male</option>
        </select>
        <h2>Preference</h2>
        <select name="Preference">
            <option value="F">Female</option>
            <option value="M">Male</option>
            <option value="B">Both</option>
        </select>

        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Modify" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one suggestion- you have multiple `<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>` in code and it's redundant. not needed

Comment: Thanks. noted & removed from my source code!